# Помогите с тестами Rspec на Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В тестах я полный ноль, посоветуйте, а лучше хотя бы начало помогите с тестами, очень прошу.

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
expose :task, -> {current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])}
expose :active_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: false).order('priority ASC')}
expose :completed_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: true).order('priority ASC')}

def index
render json: {active: active_tasks, completed: completed_tasks}, status: 200,  each_serializer: TasksSerializer
end

def show
render json: task, status: 200, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end

def create
task = current_user.tasks.create(task_params)
render json: task.id, status: 201, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end

def update
if task.update(task_params)
  render json: task, status: 200
else
  render json: task.errors, status: 422, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end
end

def destroy
if task.destroy
  return head(:ok)
else
  return head(:bad_request)
end
end

def batch_destroy
tasks = current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
end

private

def task_params
params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :due_date, :active)
end
end
```